# How to use Python properly to automation test on amazon web services

Tags: android, python, amazon-web-services, automation, appium

I speak spanish, sorry for my english. I have a mobile app and i want to make automation test using aws device farm. I'm on a Mac, i'm trying to make a simple test on my Android app: tap a login button, type user name and password and then login. 
I'm using appium to have a python code for my test, then i upload my .apk and a zip file with my test to aws but it always fails. I'm new with python, and i couldn't find an example that help me.

I follow all the steps on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-appium-python.html, but running the test gives only fails and don't take screenshots.

This is the .py code:

```
    from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
    import time
    import os.path
    import unittest
    from selenium import webdriver

    success = True
    desired_caps = {}
    desired_caps['appium-version'] = '1.0'
    desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
    desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '5.0.1'
    desired_caps['app'] = os.path.abspath('/Users/developer/Documents/AWS/workspace/APK/Squeeze.apk')
    desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'com.example.mkim.aut'
    desired_caps['appActivity'] = 'com.example.mkim.aut.SuccessfulLogin'

    wd = webdriver.Remote('http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
    wd.implicitly_wait(60)

    screenshot_folder = os.getenv('SCREENSHOT_PATH', '')
    wd.save_screenshot(screenshot_folder + "/screenshot.png")


   def is_alert_present(wd):
       try:
           wd.switch_to_alert().text
           return True
       except:
           return False

   try:
       #self.driver.save_screenshot(screenshot_folder + "/screenshot.png")
       wd.execute_script("mobile: tap", {"tapCount": 1, "touchCount": 1, "duration": 0.5, "x": 666, "y": 1519 })
       wd.save_screenshot(screenshot_folder + "/screenshot1.png") 
       wd.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.webkit.WebView[1]/android.webkit.WebView[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[1]").click()
       wd.execute_script("mobile: tap", {"tapCount": 1, "touchCount": 1, "duration": 0.5, "x": 121, "y": 726 })
       wd.find_element_by_name("(null)").send_keys("Squeeze@mailinator.com")
       wd.execute_script("mobile: tap", {"tapCount": 1, "touchCount": 1, "duration": 0.5, "x": 191, "y": 919 })
       wd.find_element_by_name("(null)").send_keys("Password")
       wd.execute_script("mobile: tap", {"tapCount": 1, "touchCount": 1, "duration": 0.5, "x": 563, "y": 1079 })
   except:
          wd.quit()
          if not success:
               raise Exception("Test failed.")
```

Comment: Ya visitaste [stackoverflow en español](http://es.stackoverflow.com)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I work for the AWS Device farm team.

1. You mentioned you are using a Mac. As per the instructions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-appium-python.html#test-types-android-appium-python-build-test-package) you should be using a Linux x86_64 machine for packaging your tests if it contains a non-universal wheel. Also you would want to make sure that you do not have any wheel that has a native library dependency.
2. You should be able to successfully detect your tests in your local environment using the command

   py.test --collect-only tests/
3. You code shows that you are setting desired capabilities. Since you already choose the device and OS version on which you want to run your tests in device farm you want to remove those desired capabilities from your code. Just have an empty desired capability object that gets passed to the driver constructor.

   desired_caps = {}
4. Your driver constructor needs to use

   wd = webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
5. The screenshot code must be

   screenshot_folder = os.getenv('SCREENSHOT_PATH', '/tmp')
6. Lastly make sure that your code runs locally and you do not have any wheels under wheelhouse folder where there is *_MAC_* named dependency as per the instructions.